# Bash - Recursively move all files in folders with given name to their parent directory

Tags: bash

I have a document library where all of my files are in folders based on category name but then they are also all in subfolders called 'pdf' as well. Is there a way in bash to scan through all of the directories in the library and move all files in folders named pdf to their parent directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following moves every file from a `pdf` folder into the parent directory.

```
find ~/some/folder -type d -name 'pdf' -print0 | while IFS= read -d '' dir
do
  find "$dir" -type f -maxdepth 1 -exec echo mv -- {} "$dir"/.. \;
done
```

Remove the `echo` once you're sure it does what you need.

Note that this will overwrite files without asking when the parent already contains one with the same name. Use `mv -i` to have it prompt you for confirmation before overwriting anything.

Comment: You're welcome. Since you asked for Bash tutorials: There are some [common problems](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ) here, and [some pitfalls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls), both on Greg's Bash Wiki – a really good resource. Also have a look at the [Bash Hackers Wiki](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/start) and the [Advanced Bash Scripting Guide](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I thought of. Its not the prettiest thing, but it works to your specifications:

```
find . -ipath "*pdf/*.pdf" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -I{} sh -c 'mv "{}" "$(dirname "{}")"/..'
```

It moves only `.pdf` files in `pdf` subfolders into their corresponding parent directories. To change the command to move *all* files in `pdf` subfolders, adjust the `ipath` argument to `*pdf/*`.

---

## Example usage

```
$ find .
.
./category1
./category1/other_dir
./category1/other_dir/c1o1.txt
./category1/pdf
./category1/pdf/c1p1.pdf
./category1/pdf/c1p2.pdf
./category1/pdf/c1p3.pdf
./category2
./category2/other_dir
./category2/other_dir/c2o1.txt
./category2/pdf
./category2/pdf/c2p1.pdf
./category2/pdf/c2p2.pdf
./category2/pdf/c2p3.pdf

$ find . -ipath "*pdf/*.pdf" -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -I{} sh -c 'mv "{}" "$(dirname "{}")"/..'
.
./category1
./category1/c1p1.pdf
./category1/c1p2.pdf
./category1/c1p3.pdf
./category1/other_dir
./category1/other_dir/c1o1.txt
./category1/pdf
./category2
./category2/c2p1.pdf
./category2/c2p2.pdf
./category2/c2p3.pdf
./category2/other_dir
./category2/other_dir/c2o1.txt
./category2/pdf
```

Comment: When piping from `find` to `xargs`, you should use `find … -print0 | xargs -0 …`.

Comment: @slhck You are correct; thanks for pointing that out. Just updated my answer.

Comment: Nice one with the `ipath`, didn't think about that. `$(dirname $(dirname {}))` can be abbreviated to `"$(dirname {})"/..` if I'm not mistaken. (In general, the arguments `{}` should be quoted to prevent files with spaces in their name or similar from appearing as multiple arguments to `mv`.)

Comment: Yep, just tested it; it works fine. `"$(dirname {})"/..` makes it a lot cleaner, too. I didn't even think about quoting it, either. Any path with spaces would break the original command.

Comment: You’re thinking DOS.  In Unix (et. al.), `*.*` gets (only) all files _whose names contain a period_.  To get ***all*** files, use just plain `*` (and even that might not get files whose names _begin_ with a period).

Comment: And I don’t understand why you have the **`/..`** –– I believe you and I are interpreting the question differently.

Comment: @Scott `*.*` will grab all files with an extension, `*` will grab **all** files; I'll fix this.  `/..` is there to move the file "up" a directory in the path.

Comment: I think this one should work but it seems to be balking because of spaces in the filenames

Comment: @portlandRyan Whoops! Needed to throw some more quotes in a few places. If a path contained spaces, more than one argument was being passed to `dirname` which threw an error. Also, I forgot to add quotes around the first `{}` argument to move, as described in a previous comment. I just fixed it!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I really appreciate the crash course in Bash